# How can I put bootstrap badge on the bootstrap tooltip?

Tags: css, datatable, bootstrap-4, badge

I try this

```
<td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"  data-placement="top"  title="<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">15</span>">
           <i class="fas fa-list-alt"></i>
    </button>
</td>
```

But I only got the `'<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">15</span>'` not html badge?
How can I put the html in the tooltip title?

I try the data-html="ture" but still fail!
I want to make the final purpose is

```
<td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-html="ture" data-placement="top"  data-placement="top"  title="<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">15</span><span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">16</span><span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">17</span>">
           <i class="fas fa-list-alt"></i>
    </button>
</td>
```

I just got the tooltip for one badge

https://jsfiddle.net/housekeepings/rm0uade9/32/

```
<html>
<body>
<table id="table_id" class="display">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
      head1
    </th>
    <th>
      head2
    </th>
    <th>
      head3
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>
   see1 
  </td>
    <td>
       <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-html="true"  data-placement="top"  title="<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">10</span>"
> 
             <i class="fas fa-list-alt"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-html="true"  data-placement="top"  title="<em>Tooltip</em> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>"> 
             <i class="fas fa-list-alt"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
     </td>
    <td>
     <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-html="true"  data-placement="top"  title="Something with badge <span class='badge badge-primary'>12</span>"> 
             <i class="fas fa-list-alt"></i>
          </button>
        </div>  
    </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried using popover instead of tooltip. I believe your requirement looks more like you wanna use popover. Chk https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/

Comment: Can u elaborate your requirement with an image?

Comment: it would me more easier to answer if you elaborate your requirement with image or in jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/housekeepings/rm0uade9/32/ here is my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add

```
data-html="true"
```

when you are adding html in title.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="<em>Tooltip</em> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>">
  Tooltip with HTML
</button>
```

Check [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/) out.

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="<em>Tooltip</em> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>">
  Tooltip with HTML
</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

your datatable js is broken which preventing the tooltip to be initialized
check this if I put before datatable it works
https://jsfiddle.net/rm0uade9/34/, you need to resolve datatable error first.

Comment: thanks~ I try data-html="true" but still fail still show the text ,as the td make the different?

Comment: @robspin create snippet in your question so we can check where exactly you stuck.

Comment: @robspin I created snippet, please make sure that the exact version you are using in your code.

Comment: I use the bootstrap 4. Can you try put this on the td table? And can show more than two badges on one tooltip? I failed and don't know why!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186445/discussion-between-just-code-and-robspin).

Comment: @robspin check my ediit

Answer (score 1):

Try This Solutions

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

   
<br> <br> <br>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"  data-placement="top" class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" title="15">
      <span >button</span>
             <i class="fas fa-list-alt"></i>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>

   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! But I want the mouse touch the button ,the tooltip show the '15' badge not the button inner text!

Comment: Thanks~But this only show one badge. I want to show four diffrent badge on one tooltip. Can other methoud?

Answer (score 1):

You can put badge or multiple badge on the tooltip
**Example**
Bootstrap 3

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
          $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
        });
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        
        
        <div class="container">
          <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
          
          <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true"
          title="Badge <span class='badge badge-primary'>12</span> <span class='badge badge-primary'>12</span>">
          
          Hover over me
          </a>
          
        </div>
       
        
        </body>
        </html>
```

Bootstrap 4

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
      <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>

      <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true"
      title="Badge <span class='badge badge-primary'>12</span><span class='badge badge-primary'>12</span> <span class='badge badge-primary'>12</span>">

      Hover over me
      </a>

    </div>

    </body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Both works perfectly.**

Comment: OP wants a solution for Bootstrap 4